# IndexError: list assignment index out of range [python + json]

Tags: python, json, discord.py

The error in the title is given to me when I try to use a command in discord.py the command is !sell my code:

```
if "!sell" in message.content:
    
    Rndm_mon = (random.randrange(1000,5000))
    with open('income.json', 'r') as f:
            h = [json.load(f)]

            

            entry = h[(len(f'| {message.author.name} '))] = (Rndm_mon)

            h.append(entry)

    with open('income.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(h, f, indent=4)

            saveJson(h, "income.json")

    await message.channel.send('You Earned ' + Rndm_mon + ' Dollars from selling')
```

the error is IndexError: list assignment index out of range and cites this part for the issue how do i fix this error?
entry = h[(len(f'| {message.author.name} '))] = (Rndm_mon)

the code is supposed to generate a random number, then add that number to a json file and then add up the previous value in the json file with the new one and in the end have a final value of the old balance and new money added together for a sort of banking system

my `income.json` file looks like this

```
{
    "| name ": "1716",
    "| name_1 ": "4291",
    "| name_2 ": "4778",
    "| name_3 ": "1254"
}
```

Comment: A couple Qs since I think you'll have multiple issues beyond this: Are you sure you want to load the json and then make it an element of a list, rather than just doing `h = json.load(f)`? And not knowing the format of your JSON file, are you trying to find someone in the loaded JSON via the message author name?

Comment: The first part of your question talking about the element of a list i dont really understand.   The second part about finding and author name and adding a balance to them would be good because thats what im trying to do. The formatting of the json file is just

{

}


if thats what you mean I apologize for not knowing much I am new to discord . py

Comment: Okay, I think I understand a little more. Are you trying to write a file that looks like... `{ "some_author": some-random-value }`? Right now, your code looks like you're trying to find someone that already exists in the JSON, but I think you either want to create an entry or update if they already exist.

Comment: yes i want that i want to get a random number and add it to the users balance and if the user has not used the command before i want to make them have balance data but if they say use the command 2 or more times to add up all that numbers to there balance so say they got 500 on the first time it would go to there data but if they get 400 on there second use of the command i want there balance to read 900

so how would i do that?

Comment: How would i do what you said? or find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easier to work this out via an answer.

This works for a JSON file where your values are numeric. In your version they're strings but that would make the solution a little more difficult to work with since you'd have to convert strings to numbers in order to do math on them.

For example, this is what the JSON should look like, and what Python's `json` module will try to write by default since you basically have a mapping of `str: int` for your `dict` keys.

```
{
    "| name ": 1716,
    "| name_1 ": 4291,
    "| name_2 ": 4778,
    "| name_3 ": 1254
}
```

Now, here's a version of your code that *probably* does what you want based on what we discussed in the comments.

Notice that there are some changes to how everything is loaded and modified.

```
if "!sell" in message.content:
    k = f"| {message.author.name} "
    val = random.randrange(1000, 5000)

    # open entire file for reading and writing
    with open("income.json", "r+") as f:
        incomes = json.load(f)

        # Either add the value to the user's balance
        # or, if they don't exist yet, create the entry
        # with the val
        try:
            incomes[k] += val
        except KeyError:
            incomes[k] = val

        # seek to beginning and rewrite file
        f.seek(0)
        json.dump(incomes, f, indent=4)
        f.truncate()

    await message.channel.send(f"You Earned {val} Dollars from selling")
```

---

If you need to convert your JSON file...

```
import json

with open("income.json", "r+") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    n = {k: int(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    f.seek(0)
    json.dump(n, f, indent=4)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: When i try to run the code it gives me an error saying,

line 165, in on_message
    incomes[k] += val
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: @SFMittens If possible, change your `income.json` file to have integers other than strings. If you're keeping a running tally of values, that makes a lot more sense. If you have to keep the values in your JSON value as strings (e.g. `"100"` vs. `100`), then this code needs to be changed to convert the values in the JSON as such.

Comment: how would i change my json file to do that

Comment: @SFMittens if it's a short file, open it and modify the values (basically remove quotes). If it's really long, I included a Python script at the bottom of my answer that can convert the file into the correct format.

Comment: where would i put this json file converter? in the json file or below the sell command?

Comment: @SFMittens make it a script called something like `convert.py`, put it in the directory where your `income.json` (or a copy of it if you want to be safe) is, then just run it as `python convert.py`. You only need to convert it once for the rest of my code to work.

Comment: Thank you so much! Also do you have any other resources or links to questions that could show me how to make it so you can request your bank data and get it back in a message depending on a user thank you so much'

Comment: @SFMittens what do you mean? Like you want to get the value after loading the JSON file for a particular user? You can load the JSON as I do in the code and then access the key for the user you want. There are multiple ways to access the value or all values in the JSON after you've loaded it, see the Dict documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries